# Manipulating git tags to get list of most recent deploy dates

Tags: git, bash

I have a rails app that is deployed to several different clients (client_a, client_b, client_c). Every time we deploy, the commit we are deploying from is usefully tagged with the deploy target and the date, for example `client_b_201409231526`. That means when I run `git tag` I get a list similar to the following:

```
client_a_20140520191236
client_a_20140527171716
client_a_20140527174741
client_a_20140528160728
client_b_20140130154136
client_b_20140130160318
client_b_20140130175443
client_b_20140130184939
client_b_20140130222100
client_b_20140203193553
client_c_20140528170811
client_c_20140806180225
client_c_20140818044549
client_c_20140903131535
client_c_20140917142911
```

I would like to find an easy way to print out the last time I deployed to each site, i.e. a way to turn the above into the following:

```
client_a_20140528160728
client_b_20140203193553
client_c_20140917142911
```

Any bash experts have a concise way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Aren't you looking for `client_a_20140528160728`, `client_b_20140203193553` and `client_c_20140917142911`, if you say the _last_ time you deployed the site?

Comment: Yes whoops thanks, I'll revise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming @Wrikken is correct in the output you actually want the following works:

```
awk -F _ '$3 > a[$1"_"$2]{a[$1"_"$2]=$3} END {for (c in a) {print c"_"a[c]}}'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using annotated tags then you should use annotated tags.  They have a date/time stamp built into them.

So presuming you are using annotated tags, then you would be able to do this

```
git for-each-ref --sort=taggerdate --format='%(refname)' refs/tags/client_a*
```

Which would print out the tags in sorted order, then you could pipe to `tail -1` for the most recent.

Comment: I'm not currently using annotated tags. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: `git tag -m "any message you want"` is all you need to create annotated tags and would probably simplify things for you